# While True loop can not be used while enable multiprocessing.pool in Python

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing pool in one of my program and i need the program to have infinite loop which means run forever... But after i applied the while True: loop in the pool program, the program seem like forever hang and do nothing at there...

I come out with a very simple Python code as shown as below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def market_update(var):
    return var*var

while True:
    alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    print alist

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = Pool()
        result= pool.map(market_update, alist)    
        print result
```

Can anyone explain why and if there any wokraround?

Edited code as suggested from Dano:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def market_update(var):
    return var*var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()

while True:
    alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    print alist
    result = pool.map(market_update, alist)    
    print result
```

Comment: @freakish, did you comment anything? the comment field is blank.

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting. Did not comment.

Comment: But the question is: what do you mean by "does nothing"? What is that you expect? There's nothing much going on in the code above. Not to mention that you spawn an infinite number of processes which will eventually kill your machine.

Comment: @freakish, I don't spot anything different what you have changed for the format...sorry about that...in fact, this is a very simple code that utilize pool in order to show my problem. I expect to see the result will be printed out repeatedly all the while...

Comment: Well it does work for me. Except that it crashes because of too many processes (you create a new pool in each iteration). Try moving `pool = Pool()` before `while True:`.

Comment: `pool = Pool()` should definitely be before `while True:` Otherwise you're going to be continuously spawning `multiprocessing.cpu_count` new processes. Other than that, this works fine.

Comment: @dano, I take out both `if __name__ == '__main__':` and `pool = Pool()` outside the while loop, but it does not help also....

Comment: @Pi-Turn What environment are you running it in? It's working fine for me on Linux.

Comment: @dano, i'm using windows 8.1...
You also take out both line of code i mentioned above right?

Comment: @Pi-Turn It's working fine for me on Windows 7, too. I'm running you example, except I put the `if __name == "__main__":` and `pool = Pool()` lines outside of the `while True` loop. Are you running it from inside an IDE? If so, try it from the command line directly.

Comment: @dano, can you take a look at my edited code updated in above question? Hmmm...weird, when i direct use the DOS command line to run, then it say my pool is not defined...

Comment: @Pi-Turn Move the entire `while True:` block under the `if __name__ ...`, too.